# Is there any (widely implemented) WS-* standard for long-running asyncronous operations?

Tags: web-services, wcf, soap, jax-ws

I am implementing a web service where clients can submit potentially long-running tasks, after which they receive an Asynchronous Completion Token (a GUID, in my case). The token may be used to poll for the status of the operation, possibly retrieving the result of the computation or a fault occurred during the computation. In addition, the operation may be cancelled at any time. Currently, the client needs to cancel the operation after it completed to free the stored result, however, I expect some form of garbage collection of results will be also needed.

This setup is nontrivial for the client: it needs to store the GUID token, poll periodically, remember to cancel the operation if it is no longer needed, handle asynchronous faults, etc. If there will be some need of authentication (WS-Security, WS-Trust), the situation will be even more complicated, for example, access to the status of an operation started by another user must be forbidden.

*Is there a widely available, interoperable WS-* standard for such asynchronous operations?* I would like to be able to call the server at least from WCF and a JAX-WS client, and possibly use the asynchronous jobs in conjunction with other WS-* standards. Rolling my own polling solution is not a big deal, however, I wouldn't like to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: It used to be the case one would use WCF together with long-running Windows Workflow Foundation workflows under Microsoft Windows Server AppFabric.  Sadly I think WS AppFabric has been marked for termination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure the WS-* standards for this. Recently our team used [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io) to implement some feature similar to yours.

As you can easily integrate Hangfire using codes, you can expose the job submitting as a interface and implement some logic to generate GUID and queue the task to Hangfire server(s), and then implement your requirement in business logic.

Comment: Thank, that's a really nice tool, although a bit out of scope for me. I will look into hangfire to implement the job queuing, but my main problem currently is implementing a job submission / status reporting interface that can be exposed to both .NET and Java.

Comment: @KristófMarussy The interface that can be exposed to both .Net and Java could be defined in your wsdl/xsd. Try this approach: when job is submitted, queue a job to Hangfire, and return GUID to client, when client request the status of the specific job (using GUID as query params), you can get the specific job status from Hangfire or you can create a status table that is shared by Hangfire work and your service layer, and return the status based on requested GUID.

Comment: Yeah, I have already defined my interface. What I am looking for is a standardized interface, so I don't reinvent the wheel. But if none exists (or at least none that is implemented widely enough to be useful, I don't want to add fancy SOAP headers just for the sake of it), then I will stick to my own interface, I guess.